# json_decode from Instagram API terribly slow

Tags: php, json, instagram, decode, instagram-api

I am fetching the data of the latest 3 posts on our company's IG feed and processing them further for an IG widget on our website.

I have ran some troubleshooting and it seems the problem is the json_decode part of decoding the raw data.

This is the JSON data fetched from IG API:

```
{"pagination": {"next_max_id": "2034341501387371123_8393175932", "next_url": "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/8393175932/media/recent?access_token=8393175932.65497a8.29744121571744afacbe375999b2525f\u0026count=1\u0026max_id=2034341501387371123_8393175932"}, "data": [{"id": "2034341501387371123_8393175932", "user": {"id": "8393175932", "full_name": "Coffea", "profile_picture": "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/vp/e88d6cdddc5697515447cde6330b03ff/5D76FD6E/t51.2885-19/s150x150/38097055_446825915802974_1995256258839445504_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent.cdninstagram.com", "username": "coffea.earth"}, "images": {"thumbnail": {"width": 150, "height": 150, "url": "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/vp/3b467c8e7913ecca2874fcbb055fd5b9/5D645F5D/t51.2885-15/e35/s150x150/59153051_2234956400103169_2351775859365829130_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent.cdninstagram.com"}, "low_resolution": {"width": 320, "height": 320, "url": "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/vp/f34190b7534acd762f6435e12b3dd610/5D5E5025/t51.2885-15/e35/s320x320/59153051_2234956400103169_2351775859365829130_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent.cdninstagram.com"}, "standard_resolution": {"width": 640, "height": 640, "url": "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/vp/8643e994a3a87ca8d93f25bcedd3ebf3/5D5FC6D8/t51.2885-15/sh0.08/e35/s640x640/59153051_2234956400103169_2351775859365829130_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent.cdninstagram.com"}}, "created_time": "1556732426", "caption": {"id": "17866442770374263", "text": "Coffee superpower \ud83d\udc4a\ud83d\udca5\nHundreds of millions of people all around the world drink coffee every day. If even a part of them starts thinking about how their everyday habits impact the environment, the results can be enormous. In Coffea, we believe the magic is hidden behind the tiniest things. Even such a common matter like coffee has the power to change the world and from ordinary people makes superheroes thanks to its superpower. Do not hesitate to ask us about the conditions and the environment where the coffee has grown up and who stands behind it.  #coffee #coffea #superpower #superman #superhero #rwanda #coffeeorigin #singleorigin #change #environment #roastedcoffee #greencoffee #coffeeimport #ecology #changetheworld #earth #brno", "created_time": "1556732426", "from": {"id": "8393175932", "full_name": "Coffea", "profile_picture": "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/vp/e88d6cdddc5697515447cde6330b03ff/5D76FD6E/t51.2885-19/s150x150/38097055_446825915802974_1995256258839445504_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent.cdninstagram.com", "username": "coffea.earth"}}, "user_has_liked": false, "likes": {"count": 34}, "tags": ["roastedcoffee", "brno", "coffee", "change", "superman", "ecology", "coffeeorigin", "superpower", "greencoffee", "superhero", "rwanda", "environment", "earth", "coffea", "changetheworld", "coffeeimport", "singleorigin"], "filter": "Normal", "comments": {"count": 1}, "type": "image", "link": "https://www.instagram.com/p/Bw7btEuB3Jz/", "location": null, "attribution": null, "users_in_photo": []}], "meta": {"code": 200}}
```

And this is the basic PHP json_decode function:

```
$latestpost_coded = file_get_contents("https://api.instagram.com/...&count=1");
$latestpost_data = json_decode($latestpost_coded);
$latestpost = $latestpost_data->data;
```

I have confirmed that this is the part of the code that makes it slow. TERRIBLY SLOW, like 10 seconds loading time. Originally the code loaded 3 latest posts, but the results are just as slow for 3 results as they are for one result.

Comment: The slow line in your code is likely not `json_decode()`, but `file_get_contents()`.

Comment: might be right, but for some reason CURL doesn't seem to work, is there another alternative?

Comment: « Some reason » is not a valid reason. Any error message returned by curl_error()? Because you’re querying over https, I’d bet it’s related to certificates. Try using curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); —do **not** use this in production— if it works, provide a valid and up-to-date SSL bundle file. See https://davidwalsh.name/php-ssl-curl-error

Answer (score 0):

You should use **cURL** instead of **file_get_contents()** as it does affect json_decode as of this discussion:

https://www.reddit.com/r/PHPhelp/comments/3hmxvs/json_decode_slow_af/

And here is the cURL attempt taken from one of the answers:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"#### YOUR URL GOES HERE ####");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $data = curl_exec ($ch);
    $json = json_decode($data,TRUE);
    // continue with normal json shit
curl_close ($ch);
```

Comment: I feel OP has no issues with JSON itself but the time taken to get response from the instagram API.

Comment: I don't think that is the case, the IG API result is fetched quickly.

Comment: Give it a try it seems like the OP has the exact same issue as you do!

Comment: I have tried this and for some reason I get no result from the CURL code - but there's no error

Comment: So $data and $json are undefined or do they have any values?

Comment: $data seems to be empty because when I try to alert its value through JS I just get an empty string, not "undefined" or anything like that

Comment: the behaviour is really weird, I have used CURL before and there was no problem, this time simply nothing happens, no errors, nothing, I just get no results. Weird. Could it be an Instagram API specific problem?

Comment: You will need to find an provide some sort of error message. Otherwise we are not able to help you unfortunately.

Comment: Well that is kind of my problem, I am not getting any error messages either in PHP itself or CURL so I have no clue where to go next

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately I solved the issue by running a cron job once per day at midnight to fetch the IG API result, save it to a file locally, and then this file is being used by the IG widget, which runs completely fine. Since it is just an IG preview window, this is more than satisfactory for my required result.

Seems like the problem was in faulty communication between our hosting server and IG server.

CURL for some reason failed to fetch the results, without throwing any errors, so this solution was a dead end for me.